# Segment Fault 11 with Dynamic C-String being Displayed from Class Function

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

Dynamic c-string 'textString' causes Segmentation fault 11 when used by a class member function to be displayed.

```
#include "Text.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

Text::Text(const char* textArray)
    {
      textLength = strlen(textArray);
      char* textString = new char[textLength];
      strcpy(textString, textArray);
      cout << textString << endl;
    }

Text::~Text()
{
  delete[] textString;
}

void Text::displayText() const
{
  cout << textString << endl;
}
```

My provided driver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Text.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Text *myString1;
    char tvshow[1000];

    cout << "\n\nWhat is the most recent TV show you watched?\n";
        cin.getline(tvshow, 1000);
        myString1 = new Text(tvshow);

    cout << "\n\nTV SHOW:\t";
        myString1->displayText();
        cout << "\t# CHARACTERS:\t" << myString1->getLength() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the Constructor for the Text class, the line `cout << textString << endl;` works as intended. However, when the main function calls `myString1->displayText();`, bash ends the program with Segmentation fault: 11.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time, effort and frustration and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately my current class is forcing me to use c-strings for now.

Comment: In what way is it forcing the use of c-strings that `std::string::c_str()` doesn't alleviate?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sure, VLAs are non-standard C++, however, I fail to see VLAs being used here.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Wow I derped pretty hard there.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it helps people to get better into your problem and reproduce it faster. See [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uJniD4G1ihK1Mkrl) as an example.

Comment: @hellow Thank you for the example. I'll try to make my posts easier to read next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionaly to [what Algirdas says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277710/1021920), your other problem is, that you actually don't assign the class member `textString` (assuming you have one), but shadow it in your constructor.
Change your constructor to something like this:

```
Text::Text(const char* textArray)
{
    textLength = strlen(textArray);
    textString = new char[textLength + 1];
    strcpy(textString, textArray);
    cout << textString << endl;
}
```

Note the missing `char *` in front of textString.

### How did I spot this?

As with any other segfault, you should learn how to debug. Your best tools are `gdb` and `valgrind`. Running this with valgrind gives me:

```
$ echo franz | valgrind ./a.out
==6222== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6222== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6222== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6222== Command: ./a.out
==6222== 


What is the most recent TV show you watched?
franz


TV SHOW:    ==6222== Invalid read of size 1
==6222==    at 0x4C32CF2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6222==    by 0x108DB6: Text::getLength() const (a.cpp:37)
==6222==    by 0x108E70: main (a.cpp:51)
==6222==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6222== 
==6222== 
==6222== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6222==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==6222==    at 0x4C32CF2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6222==    by 0x108DB6: Text::getLength() const (a.cpp:37)
==6222==    by 0x108E70: main (a.cpp:51)
==6222==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6222==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6222==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6222==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6222==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6222== 
==6222== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6222==     in use at exit: 14 bytes in 2 blocks
==6222==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 3 frees, 77,838 bytes allocated
==6222== 
==6222== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6222==    definitely lost: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==6222==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6222==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6222==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==6222==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6222== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6222== 
==6222== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6222== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
fish: Process 6222, “valgrind” “echo franz | valgrind ./a.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

You can clearly see, that the crash happens in `getLength`, because it tries to access address 0x0. When you run this with gdb, you will stop at exactly that point and can see `print textString`, that it is 0 and not properly initiliazed.

Please read [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for further information!

Comment: That char* was the issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: "_because it tries to access address 0x0._" Technically, since the `textString` is uninitialized in this case, the address itself can be equal to anything (contain indeterminate value).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I set it to `nullptr` in my example, because it was not a MCVE. Maybe I spotted it because of that.

Comment: @hellow Well, I was commenting based on the code shown, which is, just a technicality, in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You are witnessing undefined behavior, due to `strcpy(textString, textArray);` writing out of bounds.

In

```
Text::Text(const char* textArray)
{
    textLength = strlen(textArray);
    char* textString = new char[textLength];
    strcpy(textString, textArray);
    cout << textString << endl;
}
```

`strlen (textArray)` returns the length of a **null-terminated** string pointed at by `textArray`. Such length **doesn't** include the null-terminator itself. However,   [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) writes the null-terminator to the destination string. To avoid such an issue, allocate a place for the null-terminator:

```
Text::Text(const char* textArray)
{
    textLength = strlen(textArray);
    char* textString = new char[textLength + 1];
    strcpy(textString, textArray);
    cout << textString << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've made the change you suggested with `char* textString = new char[textLength + 1]` but the error still persists. I'm also still unsure how the cout statement works fine in the constructor but causes a Segmentation Fault in the displayText() function

Comment: @chasehaley Then follow the answer of Hellow. I missed the fact that you are not assigning to the class member. :/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `textLength`and `textString` are member variables of your class (of type size_t and char * respectively). You don't show the definition of your class Text.

You made a mistake in your constructor. This line

`char* textString = new char[textLength];`

should be

`char* textString = new char[textLength+1];`

to allow for the trailing '\0' that C strings have. Also you might want to bulletproof your class Text by making sure your write a copy contructor, destructor and assignment operator. Also consider what happens if NULL is passed to Text constructor. Alternatively a better option is to use std::string as a member variable, which means you can do away with the copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator (the compiler generated versions will just work); you can also do away with textLength and you can write a constructor that is member initialised.